# Can't access returned h5py object instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, hdf5, h5py

I have a very weird issue here. I have 2 functions: one which reads an HDF5 file created using h5py and one which creates a new HDF5 file which concatenates the content returned by the former function.

```
def read_file(filename):
    with h5py.File(filename+".hdf5",'r') as hf:

        group1 = hf.get('group1')
        group1 = hf.get('group2')            
        dataset1 = hf.get('dataset1')
        dataset2 = hf.get('dataset2')
        print group1.attrs['w'] # Works here

        return dataset1, dataset2, group1, group1
```

And the create file function

```
def create_chunk(start_index, end_index):

    for i in range(start_index, end_index):
        if i == start_index:
            mergedhf = h5py.File("output.hdf5",'w')
            mergedhf.create_dataset("dataset1",dtype='float64')
            mergedhf.create_dataset("dataset2",dtype='float64')

            g1 = mergedhf.create_group('group1')
            g2 = mergedhf.create_group('group2')

    rd1,rd2,rg1,rg2 = read_file(filename)

    print rg1.attrs['w'] #gives me <Closed HDF5 group> message

    g1.attrs['w'] = "content"
    g1.attrs['x'] = "content"
    g2.attrs['y'] = "content"
    g2.attrs['z'] = "content"
    print g1.attrs['w'] # Works Here
return mergedhf.get('dataset1'), mergedhf.get('dataset2'), g1, g2

def calling_function():
    wd1, wd2, wg1, wg2 = create_chunk(start_index, end_index)
    print wg1.attrs['w'] #Works here as well
```

Now the problem is, the dataset and the properties from the new file created and represented by wd1, wd2, wg1 and wg2 can be accessed by me and I can access the attribute data but i cant do the same for which I have read and returned the value for.

Can anyone help me fetch the values of the dataset and group when I have returned the reference to the calling function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in `read_file`, this line:

```
with h5py.File(filename+".hdf5",'r') as hf:
```

This closes `hf` at the end of the `with` block, i.e. when `read_file` returns. When this happens, the datasets and groups also get closed and you can no longer access them.

There are (at least) two ways to fix this. Firstly, you can open the file like you do in `create_chunk`:

```
hf = h5py.File(filename+".hdf5", 'r')
```

and keep the reference to `hf` around as long as you need it, before closing it:

```
hf.close()
```

The other way is to copy the data from the datasets in `read_file` and return those instead:

```
dataset1 = hf.get('dataset1')[:]
dataset2 = hf.get('dataset2')[:]
```

Note that you can't do this with the groups. The file needs to be open for as long as you need to do things with the groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot, comparatively new to python so had no idea what "with" was doing. I was already getting the dataset content by copying it but the groups was creating all the troubles. 
One more question, If i don't close the file reference using hf.close(), would it automatically be overwritten or closed the next time I read a file?

Comment: My understanding is that it's undetermined. The data might not actually get written until `hf.close()` is called, for example.

Comment: To force write the data I am using hf.flush() so I am hoping no abrupt behaviour, but thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

### Adding to @Yossarian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36689391/13281260)

> The problem is in read_file, this line:
> `with h5py.File(filename+".hdf5",'r') as hf:`
> This closes hf at the end of the with block, i.e. when read_file returns. When this happens, the datasets and groups also get closed and you can no longer access them.

For those who come across this and are reading a scalar dataset make sure to index using `[()]`:

```
scalar_dataset1 = hf['scalar_dataset1'][()]
```

---

### Preface

I had a similar issue as OP resulting in a return value of `<closed hdf5 dataset>`. However, I would get a [ValueError](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1779) when attempting to slice my scalar dataset with `[:]`.

```
"ValueError: Illegal slicing argument for scalar dataspace"
```

Indexing with `[()]` along with @Yossarian's answer helped solve my problem.